Installing Debian on an external hard drive: Booting, Encryption, and Swap Management
How can I install Debian on an external hard drive with the following specific configuration requirements:

Boot the operating system from the external drive
Use the same drive for data storage
Implement encryption for the Linux partition
Optimize storage performance and drive longevity, particularly regarding swap management

Technical context:

Host system: Laptop with Windows and secure boot enabled
Goal: Completely separate Linux installation without modifying internal drive


I have just deleted the cross-post on the SuperUser site, and I apologize for my ignorance.
I would like to express my sincere gratitude to those who may have downvoted my post and humbly request any insights they might have. I would be very grateful for any feedback you could provide to help me improve my future posts.
If my post was lacking in terms of research, I would like to explain that my reason for asking instead of experimenting with a virtualization is to avoid wearing out the HDD of our laptop, which is nearing the end of its lifespan. I am also concerned that the SSD will wear out (it is currently at 96% usage) on my brother's computer, which has Windows installed.
We are not financially well-off, and our circumstances may not align with your cultural or life experiences. I kindly request that you consider these factors in your assessment.

You realize you can use a tool like GParted to resize your Windows Partition?  What your asking can be done but once installed the External Drive WILL ALWAYS need to be connected if you Install the bootloader on the external drive.  To do this correctly, you're still going to need to modify the Microsoft EFI partition to contain the bootloader, and add a 3rd party bootloader like rEFInd for when the External Dive is disconnected.

From a general standpoint: Shim and MOK, a UEFI System Partition on the drive containing the kernel and initramfs and a LUKS volume with a passphrase sealed with a TPM against the boot artifacts that a Dracut module unlocks.  How you do that with Debian isn't something I know.

Have not done it with Debian, but you want ESP - efi system partition on external drive. UEFI often removes or revises a disconnected drive, but then you boot from a fallback drive entry like bootx64.efi which is how live installer boots, not a grub or Debian entry.

Is it worth it, or is it just not easy to maintain? @oldfred Thanks eyoung100 and davolfman. I thought it was just as easy as inserting a live USB.

LIve installer cannot be upgraded, You can add persistence partition for data. My external SSD is just like an internal drive. Only sometimes have to go into UEFI to boot external as Windows may have reset boot order. And external works no my other system. But none of my system need proprietary drivers which makes it easy to use on other systems. I do not plan any more flash drives as I have many, and SSD is so much faster.

Ah, that does not sound like something I would expect. Thanks for answering my questions! @oldfred
